# Trying to generate n random numbers that result in a fixed sum

Tags: python

I have been trying to get a list of random integers (without using numpy multinomial) that sum up to a certain number. I know this question has been asked before but I keep running in to issues because I want the user to be able to define the range/amount of numbers to output, as opposed to a preset number.

```
import random

def dishes():
    plates = int(input("How many dishes can you make: "))
    return plates

def budget():
    total = int(input("How much money do you have to spend: "))
    return total    


def restnum(dishes, total):
    num_dish = range(1, dishes)
    dividers = sorted(random.sample(num_dish(1, total), dishes - 1))
    return [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]

def main():
    dishes_val = dishes()
    total_val = budget()
    restnum(dishes_val, total_val)
```

main()

but i keep getting the range is not callable error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `num_dish` as if it was a function, but it actually is a variable that now stores a range object that was created using `range(1, dishes)`.
I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this program but this comment should help you.